# How to create layered line plots looping over a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
City    Year  Month Deaths  Guns     Shootings
Miami   2010    1   69      73800       701        
Miami   2010    2   99      85050       738         
Miami   2010    3   122     92650       784        
Houston 2010    1   98      92100       789          
Houston 2010    2   146     103900      799         
Houston 2010    3   162     136100      772
```

For each city, I want to create a layered line plot with the Month and Year on the x-axis and colored lines corresponding to deaths, guns, and shootings. But I don't see how to do this.

So far I tried

```
df <- shootings %>%
  select(city, date, sales, volume, median, listings, inventory) %>%
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -c(city,date))
head(df)

df<-df[df$city=='Miami',]

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = variable, linetype = variable))
```

And that can give me the layered line plot for one specific city, but is there a way to loop this through all the cities in my dataframe? Also how do I have this show the month and year labeled on the x-axis?

Last...

when I do

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

for (city_name in df$city){
    df  %>% filter(city == city_name) %>%
      pivot_longer(-c(city, year, month, date),
               names_to = "Statistic") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = date, y = log(value))) +
      geom_line(aes(color = Statistic,
                linetype = Statistic,
                group = Statistic))
}
```

I get no output. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `facet_wrap()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "City    Year  Month Deaths  Guns     Shootings
Miami   2010    1   69      73800       701        
Miami   2010    2   99      85050       738         
Miami   2010    3   122     92650       784        
Houston 2010    1   98      92100       789          
Houston 2010    2   146     103900      799         
Houston 2010    3   162     136100      772         ",
header = TRUE)

df %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, labels = month.name[1:3])) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(City, Year, Month),
               names_to = "Statistic") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Statistic,
                linetype = Statistic,
                group = Statistic)) +
  facet_wrap(City ~ Year)
```

[image]

```r
# The difference between the number of guns and the number of
# death is pretty large; perhaps plot 'log(value)' instead?
df %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, labels = month.name[1:3])) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(City, Year, Month),
               names_to = "Statistic") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = log(value))) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Statistic,
                linetype = Statistic,
                group = Statistic)) +
  facet_wrap(~ City)
```

[image]

```r
# For Month and Year on the x-axis, one option would be:
df %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, labels = month.abb[1:3])) %>%
  mutate(Month_Year = paste(Month, Year)) %>%
  mutate(Date = factor(Month_Year,
                       levels = paste(
                         month.abb,
                         2010:2010,
                         sep = " "
                         ), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-Month_Year) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(City, Year, Month, Date),
               names_to = "Statistic") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = log(value))) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Statistic,
                linetype = Statistic,
                group = Statistic)) +
  facet_wrap(~ City)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I don't want to have it faceted by year, just by the city. How would I alter this?

Comment: Edited my answer with a potential solution; does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does. I had one more question -- how could I have the x-axis show the month AND the year? I don't want to facet by the year as my dataset goes from 2010 to 2016.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I've updated my answer with a potential solution. In your case, you would need to change "2010:2010" to "2010:2016". Let me know if this doesn't suit.